# PostgreSQL: CHECK constraint for non-empty JSON objects

Tags: postgresql, constraints, jsonb, postgresql-9.4

I want to have a CHECK constraint on a JSONB column that only permits non-empty JSON objects (only `{}` with attributes, no other values like `[]` or JSON primitives).

I only want to check the "root" value, it doesn't matter what is stored in these objects.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CHECK(jsonb_typeof(foo)='object' AND foo <> '{}'::JSONB)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like any check constraint and use the <> operators. From the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/functions-json.html):

> The standard comparison operators shown in Table 9-1 are available for
>   jsonb, but not for json.

And table 9.1 shows you the not equal operator <>:

```
create table foo(
    bar jsonb,
    constraint baz check(bar <> '{}'::jsonb)
);

insert into foo(bar) values('{"foo": 1}'::jsonb);
insert into foo(bar) values('{}'::jsonb); -- fails
```

Comment: That's not what I asked. It only prohibits '{}'. I'd still be able to insert '[]' or 'true' for example.

Comment: Then put these conditions also in the check constraint using an OR

Comment: Well it was basically the question how to do that exactly. But I realised I just overlooked the json_typeof() function - that's why I couldn't just OR it because I had no idea with what. Working now, thanks!

Comment: @snøreven what was your solution in the end?

Comment: @ian-storm-taylor I just wrote an answer.